# Bibliography and bibliographic references

Tags: discussion, citation

Would anyone please provide me with some example of answers posted on math.stackexchange.com that include a bibliography as well as references to bibliographic items?

What, in your opinion, is a good style of formatting a bibliography and of referencing the items therein?

Is there a way to reference items of the bibliography such that the window scrolls automatically to the corresponding bibliographic item when the reference is clicked?

Comment: I guess that citation helper script [available at MO](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2583/new-feature-citation-helper) might be useful. There is even a feature request to [get it also here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/lets-get-mathoverflows-citation-helper-here-too).